# Undefined index ajax/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am getting the following error when I call action in controller from ajax.

**Undefined index : value.**

**This is my code in Document Ready**

unique function is to create array of unique elements.

```
                var modules =[];
                var action = [];
                var max_limit=[];
                var details ={};

$(".btn-small").click(function()
        {
        modules = unique(modules);
        action = unique(action);
        limit = unique(limit);

        details['id'] = id;
        details['cost'] = sum;
        details['modules'] = modules;
        details['action'] = action;
        details['limit'] =  limit;

        jsonString = JSON.stringify(details);







   $.ajax({ 
     url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/xxxxxxxx/actionDemo'); ?>",
     data: {'value':jsonString },
     type: 'post',
     dataType:'json',
     success: function() {
                  alert("st");
              },
      error: function(){
        alert("Error: Could not delete");
      }
});
```

This is my code in action in Controller :

```
public function actionDemo() {

        $val = $_POST['value'];
        var_dump($val);
        die();
}
```

Comment: check your `jsonString` value. I think `null` values not being submit with ajax. Try to submit a static value for debugging like `{'value':'test' }`

Comment: I have checked the values using alert the jsonString does not contain any null values.

Comment: did you check what data is being submit in console using `firebug` or other tool ?

Comment: Are you sure your post array actually has an element called `value`? From the error you're getting, I'd bet not,

Comment: var_dump($_POST['value']); this what I am using now but I am still getiing the same error

Comment: I am passing static data in value : data: {value:'test'},

Answer (score 0):

It means that "value" is not in you post data. Try to dump your POST and see what is going on.

This is probably because you are sending a JSON, so you POST will contain a JSON instead of an Array.

Comment: var_dump($_POST['value']);
I tried this but the error is still same.

Comment: That is because you are trying to get a value that is not in the array. Try var_dump($POST);

Comment: Thanks it worked but I am getting this output : array(0) { }

Comment: Now how can I retrieve my data.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you,

If you are sending `JSON` to server side you need to specify `contentType` in AJAX request. `dataType:'json'` says that what kind of response you expect from server.

Or else you can directly pass `"data: {'value':details},"` in AJAX without converting into JSON.

Comment: The code in the question won't send JSON to the server. It will send standard form encoded data. (One of the values encoded in that data happens to be JSON. but the outer-most payload is not)